# How to add facebook login to Python Django Project?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-login

I want to build a Django application where I have a simple button "login using Facebook" and it redirects you to the Facebook page allowing to log in with facebook username and password . When user clicks "login" . It should redirect me to my already defined url where i can display the user's public information from his profile. How this can be achieved ?? 
Just like 4shared.com allows to login with Facebook . I want something like that but i only want to display its public information of the user.

Comment: You must look at Facebook API page for it.

Comment: There are OAuth libraries for django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at some of the existing OAuth libraries for django. I'm using [allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), and I can definitely recommend it, even though the documentation is a bit lacking.

Here's a tutorial that helped me a lot when I was starting out:
http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

As to how to display the Facebook user's public information, you should consult the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)